# For-in loop goes one-too-far and finds 'nil' while unwrapping

Tags: swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

It looks like the following Swift for-in loop is trying to go through more elements than are in the array.

For instance, this code:

```
var list:[Int?] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

print("C-Style for loop")
for var i=0; i<list.count; i++ 
{
    var x:Int = list[i]!
    print(x)
}

print("\nFor-in loop")
for var x:Int! in list
{
    print(x)
}
```

Gets this output:

```
C-Style for loop
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

For each loop
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
... 
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I must be missing something here. Shouldn't `list.count` be the number of elements that the for-in loop tries to unwrap?

Not pictured above, the for-in loop works as expected if use an `[Int]` list instead of `[Int?]` with no unwrapping.

I am on Swift version 2.1.1.

Comment: Some strange behavior here. If you label `list` as `[Int]` and then label `x` as `Int?`, the `for-in` loop prints `nil` forever.

Comment: @Robert That behavior isn't particularly strange if you understand how it works... but Swift should probably simply prevent `x` being label as an optional like that (because it can only result in an infinite loop).

Comment: Can you briefly explain what's going? Why does this make an infinite loop?

Comment: @Robert My answer to the question you just asked doesn't quite cover that explanation, but I'd be willing to answer your question... but doing so in comments would be kind of difficult.  Maybe with the explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36253481/2792531) you have enough information to figure it out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you've done something you're not supposed to do, and thus you've stumbled on something that's probably a compiler bug (because the compiler didn't stop you). Very nice!

Now the solution. You are evidently trying to unwrap with your `Int!`. To unwrap *safely*, use `for case` syntax:

```
let list:[Int?] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for case let x? in list
{
    print(x) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
}
```

Another way (same result):

```
let list:[Int?] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
list.flatMap{$0}.forEach{print($0)} // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Comment: So forEach suffers the same problem... scary.

Comment: @Darko no it doesn't, actually; that gives me another solution — simple `list.forEach{print($0!)}` works (though of course it is potentially dangerous for other reasons)

Comment: Yes, but list.forEach{print($0)} crashes also. The need for flatMap here is scary to me.

Comment: That question mark in `case let x? in list` is really unintuitive.  I don't know anywhere else in Swift where we unwrap like that.

Comment: I also think `(same result)` is at least a little misleading.  Playground suggests that the alternative solution at the bottom of your answer is significantly more expensive: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QB8zN.png (for an array with 13 elements, 6 nil).

Comment: @nhgrif If you change it to `list.lazy.flatMap{$0}.forEach{print($0)}` that problem goes away.

Comment: @Darko `list.forEach{print($0)}` doesn't crash for me. I didn't use it because it yields Optionals.

Comment: @nhgrif `x?` is totally standard syntax for `case` pattern safe unwrapping.

Comment: Yes.  This is different from every other place where we are unwrapping optionals.  It's also, again, unintuitive.  It doesn't match the pattern unwrapping pattern we find throughout the rest of the language.

Comment: @matt You are right, I made an error in my sample code.

Comment: @nhgrif well if you really hate it don't use it. Use `for case .Some(let x) in list` instead. But `x?` was provided because people complained about _that_ one!

Answer (score 2):

Forced Unwrapping like `x:Int!` is a dangerous coding style when you can't rule out nil. The same holds for `var x:Int = list[i]!`.

This works:

```
print("\nFor-in loop")
for x in list {
   print(x)
}
```

Here you allow x to be nil and can safely check for nil later.

Now to the question why your code breaks:

Internally, swift uses `list.generate()` for the for-in loop. Generators are nil terminated which is probably the reason why your code breaks.

Comment: But the problem is that this yields Optional(1), Optional(2), etc., which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: You're correct. I suspected print is only for debugging and OP obviously knows how to unwrap. The more interesting question for me was why it fails.